# How do i connect my Brother printer in Linux Mint

Tags: laptop, printer, brother

I cant get my Brother QL-1110NWB to work, Ive installed zorin os, and now Mint and i get the same problem ive also installed on another laptop and same problem, I'm able to install the printer and the printer is recognized with "system-config-printer" and my printer is there and when i print it says waiting for printer to become available and the print status says "processing" but it will stay like that all day and nothing ever prints.

I watched a YouTube vid saying how easy adding a printer to Linux was and that the printer would just pop up and work HAHAHAHAHA, for me i wish that were true.

Any help would be great.

Laptop is a ThinkPad T510

Printer is Brother QL-1110NWB

OS is Mint

Comment: Go to Brother's product page, and install Linux drivers from Brother web site